# Trigger action when declarativeNetRequest has blocked a request

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The `declarativeNetRequest` API does not have event listeners (other than `onRuleMatchedDebug` which only works for unpacked extensions and is meant for debugging purposes only).

However I must trigger an action when a request gets blocked advising users what has happened (for example: show a modal advising the request has been blocked along with instructions on how to proceed).

What would be the best way to detect that the extension has blocked a request and trigger an action based on it? I understand the API as such has no event listeners, this question is about suggestions on how to proceed in this particular scenario.

Comment: You can use an `action` that sets the number of blocked requests on the icon badge. Alternatively, redirect to a page in the extension via `extensionPath` where you'll show the explanation.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for the suggestions. Could you elaborate more on how to use an `action` that sets the number of blocked requests on the icon badge for this particular purpose?

Comment: See `displayActionCountAsBadgeText` in the documentation.